# Property of non-regular polyhedral graph the bound for number of faces

Tags: graph-theory

With just considering the number of edges that meet at a vertex, prove that $f \geq 2 + \frac{1}{3}e$.

So what I have is that a polyhedron is $3$D so at least $3$ edges will meet at each vertex, that's equivalent to its degree. Since the sum of all vertex totals $= 2e$ then $3v \leq 2e$.

Then since a polyhedron is a plane graph, we can use $V - E + F = 2 \Rightarrow F = 2 - V + E$.

But using all of the above I got $f \geq 2 - \left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)v + e = 2 + \frac{5}{3}e$, which is not what it should be.

Where did I make an incorrect assumption? Thanks!

I'm thinking my error is in assuming $v \leq \frac{2}{3}e$ is equal to $v \geq -\frac{2}{3}e$...

Comment: It's $V-E+F=2$.

Comment: I typed it wrong in question but have it right on paper whoops

Comment: Good. But now you've replaced $v$ with $-(2/3)v$, and that can't be right.

Comment: The real problem is that $v\le(2/3)e$ wants to give you $-v\ge-(2/3)e$.

Comment: So v >= 2/3 not v >= -2/3?

Comment: No. You have $3v\le2e$. You can write that as $v\le(2/3)e$, or as $-v\ge-(2/3)e$.

Comment: The two negative signs don't cancel on both sides?

Comment: $-17\gt-42$, right? Now, is it true that $17\gt42$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you have done so far is right, just be careful with your inequality.
Like what Gerry said above, we have $v \leq \frac{2}{3}e$, so that $-v \geq -\frac{2}{3}e$ and so, by Euler's formula, we have:

$f = 2 + e - v \geq 2 + e -\frac{2}{3}e = 2 + \frac{1}{3}e$.