# polyhedron with its faces either pentagons or hexagons, prove it has at least 12 pentagonal faces

Tags: graph-theory

A polyhedron has all its faces either pentagons or hexagons. Show that it must have at least $12$ pentagonal faces.

I can show that it has exactly $12$ pentagonal faces when exactly $3$ faces meet at each vertex, however I'm having trouble with just showing it must have at least $12$ pentagonal faces.

Comment: Convex polyhedron, maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like showing that it has exactly $12$ pentagons follows easily after you show that it must have at least $12$ pentagonal faces.
For example, say you have $p$ pentagonal faces and $h$ hexagonal faces, then there are
$p+h$ faces, so $p+h=f$
Also if $e =$ # of edges, then
$5p+6h=2e$ ($5p$ counts the edges of each pentagonal face, $6h$ counts the edges of each hexagonal face, and it equals $2e$ because you have counted each edge twice)
Now using the inequality from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301770/property-of-non-regular-polyhedral-graph-the-bound-for-number-of-faces):
$$f \geq 2-(1/3)e$$
You get your desired inequality by plugging in your values for f and e, then solving for p

Answer (score 0):

Suppose it has $x$ pentagons and $y$ hexagons. Can you count the number of edges? Can you bound the number of vertices? Can you get any mileage out of Euler's formula (the one that relates vertices, edges, and faces)?